# Highly Repeating one way Hashing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, hash

**Disclaimer** This will not be used in any kind of security

I need to design/implement a one-way hash function that given a string and a number it returns me a hash of the string. The method signature should be like `string GetHash(string input, int universe)` with the following limitations:

- `universe` will be bigger than lets say 3 and will never decrease (eg, if a hash was calculated using 8 as universe, no other hash can be calculated using a universe smaller than 8)
- The hash for a static string should always be the same, regardless of the `universe` parameter, eg:
  GetHash("ABC",3) => H1,
  GetHash("ABC",4) => H1,
  GetHash("ABC",5) => H1,
  GetHash("ABC",6) => H1
- Given N strings and a fixed `universe`, the maximum number of generated different hashes cannot be bigger than `universe`, eg:
  GetHash("A",2) => H1,
  GetHash("B",2) => H2,
  GetHash("C",2) => H2,
  GetHash("D",2) => H2,
  GetHash("E",2) => H1,
  GetHash("F",2) => H1,
  GetHash("G",2) => H2,
  **NOTE increased universe**
  GetHash("A",3) => H1,
  GetHash("B",3) => H2,
  GetHash("C",3) => H2,
  GetHash("D",3) => H2,
  GetHash("E",3) => H1,
  GetHash("F",3) => H1,
  GetHash("G",3) => H2,
  **NOTE new strings**
  GetHash("Z",3) => H1,
  GetHash("W",3) => H2,
  GetHash("Y",3) => H3,
  GetHash("T",3) => H2,
  GetHash("S",3) => H1,
  GetHash("R",3) => H3,
  GetHash("Q",3) => H2

Comment: How this can be possible? Imagine that for universe = 2, you've found strings S1 and S2, such that hash(S1, 2) != hash(S2, 2). What would you then expect for hash(S1, 1) and hash(S2, 1)? According to your first rule, hashes should preserve their values, regardless of value universe, but they are different and universe = 1. Seems like you have conflicting requirements.

Comment: I suggest to go by string index, so the character code powered by the index and then modulo by the universe. for your first rule I can think of checking the existing values and return the same. cause with your example the ABC can be either 1 or 0!

Comment: @MikhailMelnik i dont see a problem there... hash(S1,1) HAVE TO BE equal to hash(S2,1)... in fact, for universe == 1, all hashes should be the same... in my real enviroment, universe wont be 1, but that should not be a problem... collision is expected AND WANTED!

Comment: I didn't mean that there is no solution. What I meant was that there is no non-trivial solution. @Dukeling gave the answer, I was thinking about. You have to specify the least possible universe, and then just get rid of that parameter, because hashes will always be smth like "hash(s) % universe". I mean there is no sense in having parameter universe with your requirements. However if values of universe will only increase in time, you should edit your post, because it is different from what you have written.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is to return the same hash for all strings and universes.

Considering this requirement:

> Given N strings and a fixed universe, the maximum number of generated different hashes cannot be bigger than universe.

Given a `universe` of 1, the hashes for all strings need to be the same.

And, given this requirement:

> The hash for a static string should always be the same, regardless of the universe parameter

The hashes for some given string needs to be the same across all values of `universe`.

This requirement actually makes the universe parameter obsolete (beyond what its lower bound is). Given some strings and a universe, that can't produce difference hashes than those strings and a smaller universe, simply because each individual string needs to have the same hash across all universes.

---

I'm assuming that any string can be valid for any `universe` parameter. If this is not the case, the scenario may be different (although the exact rules for where a string can appear will need to be included in the problem statement).

This is assuming `universe` can be 1. If the lower bound on `universe` is 2, for example, just separate the strings into 2 parts (using whatever criteria you see fit) and return one hash for the one and another hash for the other (these could also be the same hash) - this can be extended to any lower bound of `universe` by just increasing the number of parts appropriately.

---

If we ignore the first requirement, we could perhaps consider using any hash function to hash each string to a number, after which we can mod (take the remainder of, after division by) each such number with `universe` - this will limit the return values to `[0, universe)`, thus there can be no more than `universe` different hash values.

Answer (score 0):

Your first requirement cannot reasonably be met, since any reduction in the value of the universe parameter may require a string to change its hash value.  If a string has a particular hash value with `universe = 1000` then there can be no guarantee that it will have the same hash value with `universe = 2`.  The only way to meet this requirement would be to have all inputs hash to the same value:

```
function sillyHash(input, universe)
  return "42"
end function
```

Your other requirement can be met.

First define a maximum allowed size for your universe.  I would suggest a maximum of 64 or 128 bits, but larger is possible.

Next find a hash function that can deliver a hash of up to the required size.  I usually suggest the [FNV hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/), but you may want something different.  You say that you don't want a crypto quality hash, so FNV is fine for that.

Now determine the next largest power of two above the specific universe parameter.  Run your hash and truncate the result to that number of bits.  For example, if you pick `universe = 60000` then that is a 16 bit number.  You would run, say, a 64-bit hash and truncate it to 16 bits.  If you had `universe = 70000` then you would need 17 bits and truncate accordingly.  If you want to complicate things, then you could adjust the size of hash you are using as needed.

If your truncated hash is below your universe size, then you have finished.  If it is not, then re-hash, truncate and test again.  It should not take more then two or three re-hashes to find a number that is within range, given that at least half of the truncated hashes will be within the correct range from the start.

Pseudocode:

```
bitSize <- minimum number of bits to hold universe parameter

temp <- inputString
repeat
  temp <- calcRawHash(temp)
  temp <- truncate(temp, bitSize)
until (temp < universe)

return temp
```

Repeated rehashing is deterministic and so will always find the same number within the range 0 <= hash < universe given the same input string and universe size.